# How to ensure my function will receive a Vec of valid length?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to specify that a function's `Vec` argument has a certain length? Consider the possible values of a dice:

```
fn new(d_type: DiceType, face_vals: /*Vec<u32> with len() == 2/4/6/8/10/12/20*/) -> Dice {...}
```

I am writing something that lets you create a polyhedral dice (usual RPG sizes: 2, 4, 6, etc.) with specified face values. I remember that when you call a Rust function without the `unsafe` keyword the users should be able to call it however they like without fear of failure so simply checking for validity in the function and returning some **"you messed up"** error is bad Rust.

How can I achieve this?

This is a part of the code I am working on:

```
pub enum DiceType {
    D2,
    D4,
    D6,
    D8,
    D10,
    D10P,
    D12,
    D20,
}

pub struct Dice {
    dice_type: DiceType,
    face_count: usize,
    face_values: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Dice {
    pub fn new(d_type: DiceType, face_vals: Vec<u32>) -> Dice {
        let mut retval;

        //Reject if not a valid dice type 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, or 20
        //I really shouldn't be doing this should I?
        if Dice::valid_dice(d_type, face_vals) {
            retval = Dice {
                dice_type: d_type,
                face_count: face_vals.len(),
                face_values: face_vals,
            }
        } else {
            //User wont know they got an error
            //Really shouldn't need to go here. How do I avoid needing
            //error checking?
            retval = Dice {
                dice_type: None,
                face_count: 2,
                face_values: face_vals,
            };
        }

        retval
    }
}
```

**Answer**

The accepted answer shows a good use of results to return a value but the response got me thinking on how to make the code more flexible while still having a hard cap that could guarantee overflow safety for a single roll so I cut out a bunch of code and came up with the following which should let you generate any dice roll between 1-10,000 per roll with multipliers for extra rolls.

```
const MAX_FACE_VALUE: u32 = 100000;
const MAX_FACE_COUNT: u32 = 10000;
const MAX_ROLL_COUNT: u32 = 9999;

pub struct Dice {
    face_count: usize,
    face_values: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Dice {
    pub fn new(mut face_vals: Vec<u32>) -> Self {
        //User may not have values greater than 100,000
        //Index access is safe since we use the for _ in _
        for x in 0..face_vals.len() {
            if face_vals[x] > MAX_FACE_VALUE {
                //Enforce the limit
                face_vals[x] = MAX_FACE_VALUE;
            }
        }

        //User may not have more than 10,000 faces
        if face_vals.len() > MAX_FACE_COUNT as usize {
            let new_vals: Vec<u32> = face_vals.split_off(MAX_FACE_COUNT as usize);
            Dice {
                face_count: MAX_FACE_COUNT as usize,
                face_values: new_vals,
            }
        } else if face_vals.len() == 0 {
            //No 0 sided dice allowed
            Dice {
                face_count: 1,
                face_values: vec![1],
            }
        } else {
            //Normal range
            Dice {
                face_count: face_vals.len(),
                face_values: face_vals,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe wrap the Dice in a Result so I can return either a valid Dice or an Err?

Comment: Note that you do not need the retval variable. Just put the `if`/`else` stuff: `if my_bool { Dice {...} } else { Dice {...} }`

Comment: Please do not put *answers* in your *question*. You are welcome to answer your own question below and even accept that answer. This is better because it allows additional answers and those answers to be voted on by the community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use an enum that has variants with corresponding arrays of a fixed length:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Dice {
    D2([u32; 2]),
    D4([u32; 4]),
    D6([u32; 6]),
    D8([u32; 8]),
    D10([u32; 10]),
    D10P([u32; 10]),
    D12([u32; 12]),
    D20([u32; 20]),
}
```

Then you cannot have invalid value:

```
fn take_a_dice(_dice: Dice) {
    //
}

fn main() {
    take_a_dice(Dice::D4([1, 2, 4, 8]));
}
```

Comment: Note that this is a general mantra in functional programing (from which Rust borrows many things): *do not permit to represent invalid data*.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a `Result` to be able to account for possible erroneous inputs:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum DiceType {
    D2,
    D4,
    D6,
    D8,
    D10,
    D10P,
    D12,
    D20
}

pub struct Dice {
    dice_type: DiceType,
    // no need for face_count, it's a method of DiceType
    face_values: Vec<u32>
}

// an error for invalid face value inputs
enum DiceError {
    TooFewFaceValues,
    TooManyFaceValues
}

impl DiceType {
    fn face_count(&self) -> usize {
        match self {
            DiceType::D2 => 2,
            DiceType::D4 => 4,
            _            => unimplemented!() // TODO: account for all the other variants
        }
    }
}

impl Dice {
    fn new(dice_type: DiceType, face_values: &[u32]) -> Result<Self, DiceError> {
        match face_values.len().cmp(&dice_type.face_count()) {
            Ordering::Less    => Err(DiceError::TooFewFaceValues),
            Ordering::Greater => Err(DiceError::TooManyFaceValues),
            Ordering::Equal   => Ok(
                Dice {
                    dice_type,
                    face_values: Vec::from(face_values)
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea is the user should be able to give custom values for the faces. So I want a d4 that has '[1,20, 40, 60]' this should be able to support this. Your code would give '[1,2,3,4]'.

Comment: I would change the error to something like `struct DiceError { expected: usize, actual: usize }`